# Capture group of keystrokes using RxJS

Tags: javascript, keyboard, rxjs, barcode-scanner

I am creating a web interface for using USB barcode scanners. My goal is to use RxJS to capture the input from the scanners, but I'm having some trouble with the timing.

I've tried the APIs for `window`, `buffer`, `bufferWithTime`, `windowWithTime`, etc. but nothing seems to work as I need it to (groups of keypresses get cut in half). I want a buffer of data to open on the first keypress and close when there is a large enough delay between keypresses (similar to debounce, but no data lost).

Is there an API that I am missing? Do I need to use multiple Observables?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation on `Buffer`. It has several overloads, and by the sound of it you want to use a debounced stream as your closing selector. You can also explicitly control both the buffer openings and closings using another of the overloads.